# Как реализовать сохранение количества просмотров рекламы admob rewarded video в firebase?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, admob, реклама

Не знаю как реализовать сохранение просмотров рекламы для каждого юзера. Для авторизации использую firebase. Дайте подсказку ребят:)

Comment: Что бы могла значить фраза сохранение показов рекламы, обьясните пожалуйста

Comment: В новой AdMob Уже есть данная аналитика.

Comment: Не правильно пояснил:( в общем я хочу юзеру показывать сколько раз он посмотрел рекламу